# Can I use a Q1000 router as a wireless 'receiver' to provide ethernet to my desktop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wired-networking

I have an [actiontec q1000](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GGD51O).  It is hooked up to DSL via a phone cord (rj-11) and provides wireless to various devices in the house, as well as a wired connection to my desktop machine with an Ethernet cable.

I am replacing my Internet service, and USInternet is going to come in with their own modem (connected directly via fiber) in the basement, two floors away from my desktop.

I'm pretty sure the new modem will have wireless.  I hope all my wireless devices will transition smoothly, but I need to connect the desktop.

Can my Q1000 receive that wireless signal and hand it to my desktop over the Ethernet cable?

Another option is to go buy a wireless card for the desktop, but I would use my existing equipment if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common use of a router, but the router software has to support it. My quick read of [the router manual](http://qwest.centurylink.com/internethelp/modem-q1000.html) suggests that it's doable.

Note that you can get the same result with a $10 USB WiFi adapter. Depending on how much you value your time (balanced against how much you might learn by playing with the Q1000), that might be the more practical option.

Comment: Not sure a USB adapter would receive two floors away, but your point is taken.

Comment: If I wanted to learn how to do it, what is the terminology?  Is this "bridging"?

Comment: I believe "bridging" is the word. But now that I look at the manual more carefully, it appears to me that bridging support is too primitive.

Comment: Thanks, your advice was helpful. I bought a USB WiFi adapter: http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WN822N. Works like a charm.